# Neo4j find not full path to end

Tags: neo4j, cypher

For example I have relationships like:

> A->B{param1}->C->D->E
>
> A->B{param2}->C
>
> A->B{param1}->C->D
>
> A->B{param2}->C->E
>
> A->B{param1}->C->D
>
> A->B{param2}->C->D->E

I need Cypher query to find all nodes with full path from start node to end node where B{param2}, expected result:

> A->B{param2}->C
>
> A->B{param2}->C->E
>
> A->B{param2}->C->D->E

I found this way, but any another?

```
MATCH path=((n:B)-[*0..]-())
WHERE n.param2 = "value2"
RETURN nodes(path) as nodes_
```

Thank you so mach for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nodes(path)[1]` to get second node on the path.

```
MATCH path=((:A)-[*0..]-())
WHERE NOT nodes(path)[1].param2 = "value2"
RETURN nodes(path) as nodes_
```

Two caveats regarding the query.

1. Depending on the number of `:A` nodes you might want to limit number of starting nodes. E.g. by lookup some property lookup
2. You should limit the length of the path, e.g. `[*0..10]` for maximum 10 hops

Answer (score 0):

To find the nodes in all *full* paths that start at specific `B` nodes and only have outward-pointing relationships:

```
MATCH path=(n:B)-[*0..]->(m)
WHERE n.param2 <> "value2" AND NOT EXISTS((m)-->())
RETURN NODES(path) AS nodes_
```